# Losing text in double quotes on data-sqtip ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to add text to `data-sqtip` but when text contains double quotes all text after the first double quotes losing. Text may be different, with or without quotes.

```
'<div class="displayField" data-sqtip="{text}" data-anchor="bottom">'
```

For example:

- If text = `simple text in tooltip` I see `simple text in tooltip`
- If text = `simple text in "tooltip"` I see `simple text in`
- If text = `simple "text" in tooltip` I see `simple`.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
...
'<tpl for=".">',
 '<div class="displayField" data-sqtip="{name}" data-anchor="bottom">',
 '    {[this.getText(values.text)]}',
 '</div>'
...
  {
     getText: function(text) {
         return text;
     }
  }
)
```

Comment: try to use \ when you want to put "

Comment: but I get string how variable but not string

Comment: can you add your code when you get the text

Comment: @MahmoudZakal yes, I'm added code

Comment: where is the value of text placed ?

Comment: in `text`
`return text` returning variable with text value

Comment: did u try this  \" when u want to add a double quotes  in the same text?

Comment: @Emissary when i added this is code `return name.replace('"','\\"');` in tooltip losing text after `\\`?

Comment: can you add a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com)?

Comment: @aviram83, Hi, I'm fixed problem when add function `htmlEncode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fix problem need add function `htmlEncode()`

`data-sqtip="[{Ext.String.htmlEncode(text)}]"`